# How to call Eval in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, eval

How the heck do I call Eval() from codebehind?  I know this is a front-end shortcut for something like DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name"), but I cannot get this damn thing to compile.  I am missing the proper method parameters, I think.  I want to turn something like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("name") %>'/>
```

into:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImagePath(???) %>'/>
```

w/ code-behind:

```
protected string GetImagePath(????)
{
    //some code
    return "some/logical/path" + Eval("name");
}
```

The asp:Image control is in a repeater that is bound to a SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Eval` is a method on `Page` (on `TemplateControl` actually, which means that it's also present on `UserControl`). So you don't need to pass any special parameters:

```
protected string GetImagePath()
{
    //some code
    return "some/logical/path" + Eval("name");
}
```

Caution: you can only call `Eval` while databinding, but that's implicitly the case for `<%# Eval(...) %>` too, so that shouldn't pose a problem.

If you want the actual object you're binding to, use `GetDataItem()`, as `Eval(x)` basically means `DataBinder.Eval(GetDataItem(), x)`.

Comment: Well... duh.  Worked like a charm!  I thought for sure I'd have to specifically pass the DataItem to the method, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server' ImageUrl='<%# GetImagePath( Convert.ToString( Eval("name") ) ) %>' />
```

and

```
protected string GetImagePath( string image )
{
    return "some/logical/path/" + image;
}
```

Comment: This would work great except for the fact that it doesn't answer the question.  :P   The whole point is that "name" changes based on the code in the code-behind.

Comment: Yes, and it's passed in as an argument to the method so the evaluation is done first, then it is passed to your method.  Probably needs to be cast as a string, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void rProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {

        Image ProductImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("ProductImage");
        ProductImage.ImageUrl = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ProductImageUrl");

        // Or strongly typed
        Product product = (Product)e.Item.DataItem;
        ProductImage.ImageUrl = product.ProductImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to do this is to use the overload of Eval that takes a format, the aspx becomes:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("name", "some/logical/path/{0}") %>'/>
```